# Получить в script данные из select

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема, нашел на в инете код , где берутся данные из preces , но мне нужно сделать так , чтобы он брал данные из select>option , потому что у товара разные объемы из за этого разные цена , как сделать так ... Подскажите очень надо

js script

```
var prices = {
  1: 450,
  5: 430,
  50: 410
}

var pricesDiv = document.getElementById('prices'),
  countInput = document.getElementById('count'),
  summarySpan = document.getElementById('summary'),
  priceSpan = document.getElementById('price');

// for (i in prices) {
//   var div = document.createElement('div');
//   div.innerHTML = i + ' шт. — ' + prices[i] + '₽'
//   pricesDiv.appendChild(div);
// }

function calculate() {
  var val = parseInt(this.value) || 0
  var multiplier;
  for (i in prices) {
    if (val < i) {
      if (multiplier === undefined) {
        multiplier = prices[i];
      }
      break;
    }

    multiplier = prices[i];
  }

  summarySpan.innerHTML = val * multiplier
  priceSpan.innerHTML = multiplier
}

countInput.addEventListener('keyup', calculate);
countInput.addEventListener('mouseup', calculate);
```

```html
<select name="main-col" class="form-control sel">
  <option value="0" selected>Выберите </option>
  <option value="Цена: 1100р."  >1.2</option>
  <option value="Цена: 1200р." >1.5</option>
  <option value="Цена: 1400р." >1.7</option>
</select>

<div id="prices"> </div>
<div>
  <div> Количество товаров: </div>
  <div>
    <input id="count" type="number">
  </div>
</div>
<div> Итого: <span id="summary">0</span> </div>
<div> Цена за шт.: <span id="price">0</span> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var pricesDiv = document.getElementById('prices'),
  countInput = document.getElementById('count'),
  summarySpan = document.getElementById('summary'),
  priceSpan = document.getElementById('price');
discount = document.getElementById('discount');

function foo() {
  var selectedItem = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = selectedItem;
}


function calculate() {
  var val = parseInt(document.getElementById('price').innerHTML);
  var x = parseInt(countInput.value);
  if (x >= 5 && x < 49) {
    summarySpan.innerHTML = (val * x) - (x * 100);
    discount.innerHTML = "Скидка: " + (x * 100);
  } else if (x > 50) {
    summarySpan.innerHTML = (val * x) - (x * 200);
    discount.innerHTML = "Скидка: " + (x * 200);
  } else {
    summarySpan.innerHTML = val * x;
  }
}

countInput.addEventListener('keyup', calculate);
```

```html
<select name="main-col" id="mySelect" class="form-control sel" onchange="foo()">
  <option value="0" selected>Выберите</option>
  <option value="1100р.">1.2</option>
  <option value="1200р.">1.5</option>
  <option value="1400р.">1.7</option>
</select>

<div id="prices"></div>
<div>
  <div>Количество товаров:</div>
  <div>
    <input id="count" type="number">
  </div>
</div>
<div>Итого: <span id="summary">0</span> 
</div>
<div>Цена за шт.: <span id="price">0</span> 
</div>
<span id="discount"></span>
```

Comment: Спасибо , код работает правильно , но как сделать так, чтобы при количество заказа 10 цена уменьшалась в каждом случаи на 100 рублей ?

Comment: @kirilly228 всмысле, скидка на определенный % , если заказал > 10?

Comment: да , если количество 5-49 цена уменьшалась на 9 процентов , а если 50-150 уменьшалась на 18% , просто только начал изучать js , сильные проблемы

Comment: @kirilly228 изменил..

Comment: я наверно вас достал, но в данный момент вы мне нужны больше воздуха  ,ах ... Я немного перепутал , есть цена при объеме 1.2 = 1100 , при 1.5=1000 , а при 1.7= 1000 ( в select они отмечены ) и при количество 5-49 их цена становиться меньше ровно на 100 рублей , а при 50-149 их цена становиться меньше на 200 рублей ровно , если вы мне поможете буду дико благодарен )))

Comment: @kirilly228 принцип тот же... исправлено..

Comment: спасибо огромное ! теперь понял )

Comment: у меня не получается сделать так , чтобы по этому коду работала несколько selectov ,в чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: @kirilly228 что значит несколько?

Comment: 3 меня должно быть 3 inputa  с вводом количества , везде разные select

Comment: @kirilly228 ну так в чем проблема? если не хотите оптимизировать функцию, сделайте 3 на подобии foo();

Comment: я пробовал , но не получается , один работает а другие нет, я менял id='MySelect' на другие id, менял название функций в js , все менял - не выходит

Comment: @kirilly228 напишите пример вашего кода в https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=C4hQf2mwq9

Comment: Извините , я нуждаюсь в вашей помощи, если вы увидите , ответьте пожалуйста !

Comment: Помните , вы помогали мне с этим кодом , и тут возникла проблема ...На сайте , когда не выбираешь один из из options он не работает . Как сделать ,что по умолчанию в калькуляторе стаял первый из этих options , selected пробовал , ничего не вышло

Comment: @kirilly228 присылайте код...

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/578195/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80/578215#578215

Comment: @kirilly228 что именно не получается?

Comment: если в селектере не выбрать , то он начинает считать в минус , можно ли задать какое нибудь дефолтное (например 450 для первого блока), чтобы она сначала включался , но можно было бы выбирать как и сейчас

Comment: @kirilly228 ок, я понял. в тех селектах в которых по умолчанию стоит "Выберите" в функции calculate нужно сделать проверку(если ничего не выбрано, то не производить расчет) и тогда выдавать сообщение по типу: "Сперва выберите размер( или что там у вас)"

Comment: да , если так можно сделать !

Comment: @kirilly228 https://jsfiddle.net/CRafT/1xmzooqf/

Comment: вы меня уже второй раз спасли !! Может вам выплатить символически ?

Comment: @kirilly228 )))) не надо...

Comment: Тогда , просто спасибо )